# React test component with setInterval function call in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have below component class for which I am trying to write the tests. However, for some reason the function inside the setInterval is not getting called in my test cases.

```
export class SomeClass extends Component {

  public componentDidMount() {
      setInterval(() => this.doSomeWork(), 1000)
  }

  public doSomeWork() {
     ....
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('run test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
     jest.useFakeTimers()
     const wrapper = mount(<SomeClass store={store} />)
     expect(wrapper).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

It doesnt seem like jest.useFakeTimer() is working here as the doSomeWork method is not at all executing when running the above test.

I have gone through other answers which all suggested to use the jest.useFakeTimer but it doesnt seem to be working for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the test failing?  Post specifically the problem you observe (beyond "it doesn't work") and how you know that function is not executing

Comment: @possum: test is not failing. I just dont see the lines covered for the method called in setInterval. Also, for testing I have put a log in the doSomeWork method which is not being logged

Comment: @sf9251 You never executed runAllTimers, runOnlyPendingTimers or advanceTimersByTime or any kind of function that would [trigger the setInterval callback](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks)

Comment: @HMR Appreciate your suggestion. This indeed is what I was missing. Glad you pointed out. Thanks, you can post the same as answer.